# How to replace whole lines with match substrings using 'sed'

Tags: sed, grep

I was trying to find a way to know the emails written in source codes. I found a way to get the information I was looking for using `grep`, but as I'm not really familiar with `grep` syntax I'm looking at how it could be done with `sed` for the futur. What I did with grep is:

```bsh
grep [0-9a-zA-Z]@[0-9a-zA-Z] ./ -r | \
grep -o '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' | \
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

That (second) `grep` expression is found on the net and have a bunch of miss matches.

My sed expression so far was:

```bsh
grep -h [0-9a-zA-Z]@[0-9a-zA-Z] ./ -r | \
sed -nre 's/.*\([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*\).*/\1/p' | \
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The problem with it is that `sed` regex are greedy. I thought of using `/expression/s/.*/\1/`, but `sed` does not find `\1`, as I guess the matches are limited to the `.*`.

Comment: It would help if you'd add a sample of the content and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -rhoE '[[:alnum:].!#$%&'\''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[[:alnum:].]+' .
```

or perhaps:

```
grep -rhoP '(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'\''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])' .
```

(based on [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address) found at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression))

---

Regarding the question:

- Instead of using `.*` try negating the character class used in the subexpression. Eg:

```
sed -nE -e 's/[^[:alnum:]._-]*([[:alnum:]._-]+@[[:alnum:]._-]+)[^[:alnum:]._-]*/\1\
/gp'
```

Comment: The dot does not need te bu escaped in a character class (the backslash is literal inside the class). You could use `[^[:alnum:].-]` for less typing.  Also note that inserting newlines with the `s` command in `sed` is supported by GNU `sed` only (likewise, your `grep` example at the end requires GNU `grep`).  There is also `[[:punct:]]` to match punctuation characters.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I use this ERE (so it'll work in `grep -E`, `sed -E`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.):

```
[0-9a-zA-Z._%+-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}
```

based on the regexp at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html. Add word boundaries if your tool supports them, without sample input/output I can't suggest anything else to bound the email addresses. I specifically do not use character classes so I only get English letters as that's what works best for my application.